# Gitlab 4:Deadline Exceeded when uploading large file

Tags: gitlab, large-files

I'm trying to upload a large file 800mb to my Gitlab repo but I am getting a deadline exceeded error. I'm wondering if there was any workaround or if I can increase the timeout somehow.